# How do I properly refresh DataTable from DB (Oracle)

Tags: .net, winforms, odp.net, data-access

After extensive digging, I still can't figure the proper way to do following basic task in .NET (maybe I just can't find something very obvious, sorry if so).

In a WinForms application, there is some SQL-query (`"select * from tab1 where col1 > 5"`); result of this query is stored in a DataTable-Object.

After some time passes, I want to refresh the data from the DB. Since there is a PrimaryKey, I use the `DataAdapter.Fill` with the table object, and it does update the values just fine. What it **does not** do is **delete** the rows no longer in the DB-table.

See the code below.

```
    Private connectionString As String = "Data Source=DBName;User Id=my_user;Password=my_pwd;"
    Private Sub LoadData(dt As DataTable, sql As String)
        Using conn = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString)
            Dim cmd = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using da = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
                conn.Open()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns(0)}
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        LoadData(dt, "select * from tab1 where col1 > 5")

    End Sub
```

**EDIT1**: creating a new instance of the DataTable or using it's `Clear`-Method has undesirable side-effects if the object is bound to a grid (current record is lost; need to redraw every single row).

Now, there is a *solution*, which I consider a *workaround*.

If we mark all rows in the DataTable-object as "Deleted" first and then get all data from the DB, it will reset the status of existing rows to `Unchanged`, leaving those not on the DB anymore as `Deleted`; consequent `AcceptChanges` removes them from the DataTable.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            r.Delete()
        Next
        LoadData(dt, "select * from tab1 where col1 > 5")
        dt.AcceptChanges()

    End Sub
```

This works, but feels ugly to me.

There is also a feature called ["Database Change Notification"](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/changenotification/odpnetchg_otn.htm), which is really nice because it can let one know the `rowid`s of added/modified/deleted rows, but we would need to explicitly select the `rowid` to delete rows from the DataTable -- which is ugly (and not always easy).

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: honestly to just refresh, throw the previous result away, and reload. either set dt = new datatable prior to function call, in which case the results will be loaded into a fresh datatable, or you can call dt.clear prior to refilling.

Comment: @Jeremy this would have undesirable side-effects if the DataTable is bound to some grid (I added an EDIT to the post to clarify this).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more fundamental change, but I think its better not to use DataTables, but instead use a BindingList. When the list is updated all changes are then automatically reflected in the UI.

This is a rather long example. Using this method, the list is refreshed from the database but the binding remains so you're not changing the datasource on the control.

A base class for the data to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
Public Class INotifyBase
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

End Class
```

This example uses a class called User

```
Public Class User
    Public Sub New(userID As Integer, userName As String)
        Me.UserName = userName
        Me.UserID = userID
    End Sub

    Public Property UserID As Integer

    Public Property UserName As String

End Class
```

Here is the binding list of the class

```
Public Class MyUsers
    Inherits BindingList(Of User)

    Public Sub New()
        'TODO Add database code to build list

        'Example list
        Me.Items.Add(New User(1, "Dave"))
        Me.Items.Add(New User(2, "John"))
        Me.Items.Add(New User(3, "Andrew"))

    End Sub

End Class
```

Create a class to bind to the UI.

```
Public Class UIBinders
    Inherits INotifyBase

    Private _users As MyUsers

    Property Users As MyUsers
        Get
            Return _users
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As MyUsers)
            If (_users Is Value) Then Return
            _users = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Finally in the form declare the binder class and bind to the grid. The button click event loads the data.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Binder As New UIBinders

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        DataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Datasource", Binder, "Users"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub bnLoadTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnLoadTable.Click
        Binder.Users = New MyUsers
    End Sub

End Class
```

I realise this seems a long winded example, and may be overboard for your original question, but I find it useful because once the scaffolding is in place, everything else takes care of itself. Also it separates the UI from the business logic.

Comment: Could You please explain how does using BindingList solve the problem of properly updating its content from the DB?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The data I'm showing exists in 3 places: the DB, the cache (`dt` in my example) and in the UI (some grid). The connection between cache and UI is fine (there is a grid I can use to show and edit the cache). The connection from cache to DB is fine too. Only the DB to cache is not ok, and only if a row is deleted on the DB by someone else. An immediate reaction to a DB change isn't a requirement either, onButtonClick is fine.